# sorting a mongoid collection before map reduce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, sorting, mongoid

how can i sort a collection **before** performing a map reduce operation on it?
lets say i have this collection:

`{a:1, b:1}, {a:2, b:2}, {a:3, b:e}, {a:1, b:7}`

now, i want to sort by the value of `a` and return the sum of `b` and i need only the x results (sorted by `a`). how can i sort by the `a` first?
in [mongo](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/) i can do something like:

`mapReduce(map, reduce, {sort: {a:1}} )`

how can i do that on mongoid? it only accept 2 parameters for the `map_reduce` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after checking this issue i found 2 ways:

1 - using the native driver, something like:

```
db = Mongoid::Sessions.default
db.command(
  mapReduce: "messages",
  map: map,
  reduce: reduce,
  query: { ... },
  sort: { "a" => -1 },
  out: { inline: 1 }
)
```

2 - by looking in the mongoid [code](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/f4be91d037fd9048872f847a71286f9512aa862a/lib/mongoid/contextual/map_reduce.rb#L249) i saw that even though `map_reduce` get only two params (map and reduce), you can chain other params (like sort) and then you can do something like:

`Message.sort(a: -1).map_reduce(map, reduce)`

**IMPORTANT**: in any case, you must make sure that the field you sort by has index, as explained [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#dbcmd.mapReduce):

> The sort key must be in an existing index for this collection.

i hope it helped.